# Parsing string to DateTime with TryParseExact with other language culture and format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, tryparse

I have tried to parse a string that represents a date in Spanish (Chile) when meaningful data is missing -- the year. I hoped that the DateTime class will know how to find the latest date that match. Any suggestions?

```
  public void TestDateParsing()
    {
        string strDate = "MIE 25";
        CultureInfo cl = new CultureInfo("es-CL");
        DateTime date= new DateTime();
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate,"ddd d",cl,DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            //print the variable date...
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does `it does'nt works for me` mean?  See [Ask]

Comment: As Soner has already mentioned it seems to be wednesday. So there are 12 monts in a year which could be 25th. There's probably a wednesday, but wait, we even don't know the year.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Exactly. _Even_ if we know the year part, let's say `2015`, both february and november has `25`'th day as a wednesday :) Parsing methods can't decide that thank god.

Comment: @SonerGönül: hmm, then i know the solution to the puzzle: OP wants the first `DateTime` which is wednesday,25th and where the year doesn't contain multiple. Why doesn't `DateTime.Parse` doesn't support it by default?  ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good luck with that. Start the year `0001` :p When it will be open sourced, we can improve it with a pull request :)

Comment: I'm sorry,that's my first question in Stackoverflow, i'm working with real dates from websites so the idea was to parse that date with the current month and year or the next month

Comment: It's possible after all :) check out my answer below. @SonerGönül

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would like to hear your opinion too

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because your `strDate` doesn't have enough information for parsing a `DateTime` instance.

`mié` (even it's not the same as `MIE`) seems abbreviated day name of a wednesday in `es-CL` culture, so, what result should be as a `DateTime` of `25 Wed` string?

We *can't* know that, same as parsing methods..

Your string needs more specific information about your date or time part for parsing it successfully. Without these information, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I'm sorry,that's my first question in Stackoverflow, i'm working with real dates from websites so the idea was to parse that date with the current month and year or the next month.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while and I forgot about that question. After going over your answers (2 years ago Haha) I found that there is a way to parse a date according to the current year calendar.
According to 2017 "Martes 21 de marzo" (Tuesday, March 21) is a valid data and the code below will work, but if you will change it to "Martes 24 de marzo" for example, exception (format exception that says "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect." to be more accurate) will be raised cause that date doesn't exist at the current year.
I must mention that I used that code to parse dates in scrappers that I used to build and I assumed that the dates that I'm receiving are valid dates.
I hope that that piece of code will help someone somehow.

```
string strDate ="Martes 21 de marzo";
CultureInfo cl = new CultureInfo("es-CO");
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(strDate, cl, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: This is _not_ the same string you mentioned in your question. It includes day information also. In such a case, it _can_ be parsed with the current year _if_ such a date exist. But again, those are completely different strings.